# How to conditional render css inline

Tags: css, reactjs

Basically, I can do this because, I conditional render backgroundColor, but I want also render a position. I want some data was display on right, other on left. My problem is I have no idea why any of css I used not work:  `align, alignText, position`
work halfy `float` but it cause other thing was destroyed in half.

```
      {Data.map(i => (
        <StickyContainer
          key={i.id}
          className="container"
        
          style={{  alignText: "right", backgroundImage: `url("/zalety/${i.id}.jpg")`, 
        backgroundSize: "cover", 
    }}
        >
          <Sticky>
            {({ style }) => (
              <h1 style={{ ...style, background:   "#ae4a84", textAlign: "center" }} > {i.title} </h1>
            )}
          </Sticky>

          <h2 className="text-center" style={{width: "45%", backgroundColor:  (i.color ) ? `${i.color} ` : "white",
     
        
        }}>{i.content}</h2>
          
        </StickyContainer>
```

I tried to use a component such as `ExampleCard` or something and there put this  but it caused error with class/functional component.

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally add the inline css, since this is a JS Object that you're passing in to the style props, you can construct the object along with JS spread operator like below:

```js
 ...
 <h2 className="text-center" style={{width: "45%", backgroundColor:  (i.color ) ? `${i.color} ` : "white",...(<condition for right alignment>)?{<CSS props for right alignment>}:{}}>{i.content}</h2>
...
```

Replace the each <> with the appropriate data. The above change will make it so that you only apply the CSS when the condition is true.

For styling and position to the right or left, I usually do something like `{position:'absolute', right: 0}` but this will only work if your `StickyContainer`, or whatever the direct parent of your `h2`, has a `position` of `relative`, otherwise, it will adjust itself with the most recent parent that have the `position` of `relative`.

Comment: ```StickyContainer ``` is from ``` react-sticky'; ``` Unfortunately,  position absolute and right: 0, do not work.

Answer (score 0):

To future generation, after traing all methods to transform it, just I had a golden shot:

```
transform: (i.position == 'right') ? "translate(100%, 0)" : null,
```